# Formlets implementation in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming

The [formlets paper](http://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/links/papers/formlets-tr2008.pdf) mentions that they made an implementation in Python, but my google-fu fails. Is there a free implementation of the paper in an imperative language?

Comment: have you googled the email addresses of the authors and asked them for the implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the authors in question, and they answered that the python implementation was nothing more than a proof-of-concept, and they didn't find have the original implementation anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The home link for that project's code is this: http://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/links/formlets/

There is a [link](http://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/links/formlets/ocaml-formlets-june-2008.tar.gz) on that page that will download a tar.gz in OCaml, which is an [imperative capable](http://caml.inria.fr/) language. Hopefully that helps you achieve what you want.

The other language implementations (such as python) aren't online, I second the idea of emailing the authors if you want python specifically - I've met them before and they are likely to share. If you get it, link here!